# How do I transform a sequences of maps into a sequence of maps with selected keys?

Tags: clojure

I have a sequence of map like this

```
({:a 1 :b 2 : c 4} {:a 3 :b 3 :d 4})
```

And I want to turn this into a sequence of more compact maps that just have the :a and :b keys, like this:

```
({:a 1 :b 2} {:a 3 :b 3})
```

What's the most concise way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The built-in function [select-keys](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/select-keys) is what you're looking for.

```
(let [in [{:a 1 :b 2 :c 4} {:a 3 :b 3 :d 4}]]
  (map #(select-keys % [:a :b])
       in))
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution would be to write a function that takes the keys you want to keep and returns a fn on maps. Then map it over the sequence of maps:

```
(defn keep-keys
  [ks]
  (fn [m] (select-keys m ks)))

(map (keep-keys [:a :b]) '({:a 1 :b 2 :c 4} {:a 3 :b 3 :d 4}))
```